# Can't get the right value for height of uiwebview

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to get the value of uiwebview this way:

```
            var webview = self.articleContent

            println(webview.frame.size.height)
            // prints 300

            // rendering the webview
            webview.loadHTMLString(articleHtmlContent, baseURL: nil)

            // getting the height of the webview
            var output = webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.scrollHeight;")!

            println(output)
            // prints 300 - again
```

So it looks like the output I get is the height of the uiwebview instead of the height of the HTML content.

How can I get the height of the HTML contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use its scroll view's content size which will be available after the web view responds to `webViewDidFinishLoad` on its `UIWebViewDelegate` like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
  CGFloat totalHeight = webview.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

Comment: it's still returns 300

Comment: Have you made sure that the web view finished loading its content before checking its content size?

Comment: That was the problem! Please edit your answer and I'll mark it as correct.